# Android/iPhone link styling

Tags: android, css, hyperlink

I'm working on mobile site. I've found that regular a:active styling works for iOS if I include `ontouchstart=""` in the link code.

For some reason Android devices do nothing when links are clicked.

My goal is to change the background-image position on press, is there a simple/effective cross platform solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add "click" event listener to the element, and change the background-image position with a new css class.